# List Vertical Align in IE 9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

[image]

Hi all, I am having problem with using `<li></li>` in the IE browser. I have tried using `display:block` and `display:table` to correctly align the second line of each bullet with the first, but neither has worked.

Here is the list:

```
 <ul class="a">
     <li>
         <span>The customer provides the database schema files, which include SQL statements (DDLs of all the database objects and stored procedures), and the application source code.</span>
     </li>
     <li>
         <span>Fujitsu performs the migration analysis. An experienced consultant with the help of our proven migration assessment tool will analyze your organization&#x27;s database environment, assessing the infrastructure, schema and applications.</span>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css place this adjust number of px to exact location where you wish for it to start.

```
 ul.a li {
   text-indent:10px;
 }
```

or try to use padding instead of list style property.

Comment: Yah , but it works on  Chrome , just not on Internet explore

Comment: I was using list-style-position : inside. i should probably get ride of this property

Comment: probably could you show your css that you are currently using

Comment: It works , as soon as i delete the LIST-STAYLE-POSITION PROPERTY and using padding. thanks @ AAnkudovich